# Asynchronous Resets

Tags: digital-logic, fpga, reset, vlsi

I am designing an FPGA that will include state machines and counters both of which needs to be reset, I have heard that it was always better to use synchronous resets, is it true?

I am not sure that my synchronous state machine works:
What will be the difference if I use synchronous or asynchronous resets?[image]

Comment: "`i have heard that it was always better to use synchronous resets`"... Where did you hear that?

Comment: Always use synchronous de-assert for resets. Nothing wrong with asynchronous assert if you're putting all connected logic into reset during assert.

Comment: The only thing I see with asynchronous reset is that it could introduce setup/hold-time violations. You reset your flipflop, but you will have circuits using the output of your flipflop. You might get a synchronization problem there. (analogGuy)

Comment: @the dude  It is unfortunate that your code posting is a graphic as neither example is correct.   Your synchronous reset is missing clock.   Your asynchronous reset uses "else if" where it should use "elsif"

Answer (score 5):

The problem with asynchronous resets is that you need to avoid metastability, which happens when the timing constraints are violated. In particular you need to ensure the input signal is stable for the required setup time before the clock edge can occur, illustrated in the diagram:
[image: metastability]
where C2 is your clock and A is your flip-flop input.

An FPGA logic unit has a form like this:
[image: fpga]
When you de-assert the reset signal the input to the flip-flop changes from the reset value to the next value. If the clock edge occurs sooner than the setup time requirement, you will get a timing violation. Similarly you can get a hold time violation, if the de-assert occurs just after the clock edge.

This is why you need to ensure that there is a sufficient interval between the clock edge and the reset de-assert. A straight forward way to do this is to use a synchronous reset de-assert or a fully synchronous reset.

Comment: OP asked about using synchronous vs asynchronous resets in their design.    You are correct in your statement that internally, reset needs to be synchronously de-asserted - but you have not explained in any way how this applies to the OP's question.

Comment: @JimLewis my last two paragraphs explain exactly this.

Comment: > When you de-assert the reset signal the input to the flip-flop changes from the reset value to the next value.
Could you clarify that? The code posted reacts at the positive edge of the reset, therefore the flip flop value will change when the reset is asserted, won't it?

Comment: @Martel The logic in the flip-flop stops the D input from changing its state for as long as the reset signal is active. When you de-assert the reset signal too close to the clock edge you can cause a timing violation. In short, the flip-flop needs a certain amount of time to recover from a reset, i.e. reset recovery time. A simple reset circuit will sit in between the input of the flip-flop and the input of the internal latch in the flip-flop. If you de-assert too close to the clock edge, the input to the internal latch will not be stable for long enough to satisfy the setup time.

Answer (score 3):

FPGA logic cells typically have a dedicated asynchronous reset input.  In many cases, there is a global asynchronous reset that can be used for a large number of cells with no extra routing resources.  Synthesis software typically groups cells into blocks of common reset and uses the global reset for the largest group of cells.

Synchronous reset requires the reset to be included in the logical inputs to a cell, reducing the available logic inputs by 1 and also require routing resources to get the reset to each cell.

As mentioned above, as long as you synchronously deassert your "asynchronous" reset, by driving the reset with the output of a synchronization FF, you will not have any timing issues.  In the process, you will save logic and routing resources.

Comment: Spot on, crj11.

Comment: Is the code on the left a synchronous deassertion of the asynchronous reset?

Comment: It looks to me like the left code would just cycle through INIT, RESETASSERT, ERSETDEASSERT, INIT ... as long as rst_gen is not asserted.  Also, there is nothing to set the initial state of the state machine.  Actually, there is no "rising_edge(clk_sys)" in there, so I'm not sure what it would do.  It certainly is not synchronous without some edge related transition.

Answer (score 3):

Here it is in a nutshell.

Asynchronous assertion (of the reset), and synchronous de-assertion (or release) of the reset.

Here's a typical application.  Two different clock regions (33 MHz and 50 MHz, asynchronous wrt one another).

[image]

Comment: My work, or a representation thereof of an FPGA design I did.

Answer (score 2):

Asynchronous vs Synchronous resets is like a debatable topic. Generally speaking, async resets are faster than sync resets because of independency on clock. But async resets are prone to metastability issues as pointed out by another answer in the post, so the de-asserting should be synchronous. This is done by a flip-flop based synchroniser circuit.

Sync resets are not prone to glitches unlike async resets. Also they use smaller flip-flops and saves area. In contrast to async resets, sync resets lines are treated like data lines and hence routing gets complex, and achieving timing becomes tighter. Also in clock gated circuits, sync resets can't put the system into an initial state, without clocking it. But exceptions are there with regard to performance and area utilization.

Say for example in xilinx FPGAs, as per their HDL coding guidelines,  if you are dedicated blocks like block rams or multipliers, sync reset has to be used for best performance and optimal area utilization. Using async resets, deteriorate the performance by 50% in such cases. In general cases, often async resets inhibit performance and area optimization too.

Refer to: https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/white_papers/wp231.pdf

Comment: WRT RAM, I suspect is says, don't use reset on the core of the RAM as then it will have to be implemented as registers.    Likewise for pipelining multipliers - reset on the registers that you want retiming/pipelining on is likely to prevent that operation.

Answer (score 2):

The OP seems to be asking, should I use synchronous or asynchronous reset.   First, I agree with the discussion that for each clock domain, there needs to be a circuit that causes the reset distributed to the flip-flops to be synchronously deasserted.

When you are using a dynamically loaded part, such as Xilinx or Intel (formerly Altera), there is little benefit to Asynchronous reset - it may be nominally faster, but we are talking about fractions of a clock period - so more than likely Synchronous Reset is preferred for these technologies.

OTOH, for a part that has its personality at powerup (ASIC, fuselink, flash based) like many of the Microsemi (formerly Actel) parts and ASICs, then you may get a benefit using Asynchronous reset because at powerup on the board some clock oscillators are not running for a large period of time, and hence, Asynchronous reset can be used to put the outputs into a safe state.   Whether this is necessary or not depends on what those outputs control.

The trouble with Asynchronous reset is that you have to deal with noise immunity problems - glitches are a big deal.    Synchronous reset can easily add glitch filters in the logic that causes the reset to deassert synchronously.    Asynchronous reset cannot as it will loose the asynchronous assert if it does, so the filters for asynchronous reset will need to be analog based.

Answer (score 1):

In general it's safer to use a synchronized version of the reset signal that ensures that the trailing edge of reset is synchronized with the clock, but use async reset within the block itself (like you show in your first VHDL example.)

This ensures that:

- the block is reset even in the absence of a clock
- no async path timing issue

The latter problem is that synthesis will flag an async reset going to a sync block unless the reset signal is set to be a false path.