# Don't understand why this clock interaction is unsafe

Tags: fpga, clock, timing-analysis

I'm starting with static timing analysis. I have a very simple Verilog design that has clock interaction problems, and I don't see why. It just has a counter whose LSB is sent to an LED. Could I get some help?

### Code

```
module dff #(parameter N = 32) (
    input  wire [N-1:0] d,
    input  wire         en,
    output reg  [N-1:0] q,
    input  wire         clk,
    input  wire         rst
);
    always @(posedge clk, posedge rst) begin
        if (rst)
            q <= 32'b0;
        else if (en == 1'b1)
            q <= d;
    end
endmodule

module clk_div #(parameter POL = 1'd0, parameter PWIDTH = 8'd4) (
    output  reg         div_clk,
    input   wire        clk,
    input   wire        rst
);
    reg [31:0] timer;

    always @(posedge clk or posedge rst) begin
        if (rst) begin
            div_clk <= POL;
            timer <= 0;
        end else begin
            if (timer < (PWIDTH - 1)) begin
                timer <= timer + 1;
            end else begin
                timer <= 0;
                div_clk = ~div_clk;
            end
        end
    end
endmodule

module counter7s_top(
    output  wire [15:0] LED,
    input   wire        CLK100MHZ
);
    //
    // Clock generation
    //
    wire clk1;

    clk_div #(.POL(1'd0), .PWIDTH(500)) cd(clk1, CLK100MHZ, 1'b0);

    //
    // Counter
    //
    wire [15:0] cc, cc_p1;

    dff #(.N(16)) c(cc_p1, 1'b1, cc, clk1, 1'b0);

    assign cc_p1 = cc + 1;

    //
    // Output
    //
    assign LED[0] = cc;
endmodule
```

### Timing constraints

```
create_generated_clock -name cd/clk -source [get_ports CLK100MHZ] -divide_by 1000 [get_pins cd/div_clk_reg/Q]
```

### Timing analysis reports

There are no errors, slack is positive. However the clock interaction report is:
[image]

### Schematics

[image]

---

I have tried the following clock constraints (separately) to solve the problem but none of them work:

```
set_clock_groups -name asd -asynchronous -group [get_clocks *]
set_clock_groups -name asd -physically-exclusive -group [get_clocks *]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed the problem by making those two clocks physically exclusive with

```
set_clock_groups -name g2 -physically_exclusive -group [get_clocks cd/clk] -group [get_clocks sys_clk_pin]
```

My syntax was wrong before.

## EDIT

I have found something obvious but interesting.

In my first clock constraints, `cd/clk` is a result of dividing `sys_clk` by 1000. However, if I indicate in the constraints that `cd/clk` is `sys_clk / 2`, (and I remove the physically_exclusive constraint) all the problems disappear, I get this:

[image]

So my understanding is that if `sys_clk` is divided by 1000, then the interaction between these 2 clocks can indeed cause a setup and hold violation, even if they are in phase. E.g.: consider a signal `s` that changes at the 999'th positive edge of `sys_clk`. `cd/clk` will change at the 1000'th because of the clock divider, so `s` violates the setup time of a flop clocked by `cd/clk`.

However, if `cd/clk` would be `sys_clk / 2`, **and knowing that they are sync. clocks i.e.: they are in phase**, then there is no way the setup and hold violation can happen, since a signal `s` can only at the pos. edge of `sys_clk`, or right in the middle of its positive and negative edges, leaving time more than enough for the flops to scan the signal correctly.

Then again I don't think there is any problem in dividing the clock by 1000 if there are not interactions between both clocks (other than the clock divider itself), but possibly the tool will think there can be a problem, and therefore this should be excluded with a clock group or false path. **Take this with a grain of salt because I'm no way near to be an expert in STA.**

## EDIT 2

It turns out that the solution found [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/635326/hold-violation-in-clock-divider-in-an-fpga) (use BUFG for the clock divider) also fixes this. Actually, the generated clock disappears from the clock interaction diagram:

[image]

I understand nothing.

## EDIT 3

As @MituRaj explained, there are indeed 2 clocks. I re-runned synthesis and timing analysis from zero and now I can see the two clocks interaction, all green:

[image]

Maybe I had some extra constraint in my in-memory constraints or something.

In summary, these are my only 2 constraint files:

**Basys3_Master.xdc**

```
## This file is a general .xdc for the Basys3 rev B board
## To use it in a project:
## - uncomment the lines corresponding to used pins
## - rename the used ports (in each line, after get_ports) according to the top level signal names in the project

# Clock signal
set_property PACKAGE_PIN W5 [get_ports CLK100MHZ]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports CLK100MHZ]
create_clock -period 10.000 -name sys_clk_pin -waveform {0.000 5.000} -add [get_ports CLK100MHZ]

# Switches
set_property PACKAGE_PIN V17 [get_ports {sw[0]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {sw[0]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN V16 [get_ports {sw[1]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {sw[1]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN W16 [get_ports {sw[2]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {sw[2]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN W17 [get_ports {sw[3]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {sw[3]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN W15 [get_ports {sw[4]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {sw[4]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN V15 [get_ports {sw[5]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {sw[5]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN W14 [get_ports {sw[6]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {sw[6]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN W13 [get_ports {sw[7]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {sw[7]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN V2 [get_ports {sw[8]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {sw[8]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN T3 [get_ports {sw[9]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {sw[9]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN T2 [get_ports {sw[10]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {sw[10]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN R3 [get_ports {sw[11]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {sw[11]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN W2 [get_ports {sw[12]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {sw[12]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN U1 [get_ports {sw[13]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {sw[13]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN T1 [get_ports {sw[14]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {sw[14]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN R2 [get_ports {sw[15]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {sw[15]}]


# LEDs
set_property PACKAGE_PIN U16 [get_ports {LED[0]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {LED[0]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN E19 [get_ports {LED[1]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {LED[1]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN U19 [get_ports {LED[2]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {LED[2]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN V19 [get_ports {LED[3]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {LED[3]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN W18 [get_ports {LED[4]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {LED[4]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN U15 [get_ports {LED[5]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {LED[5]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN U14 [get_ports {LED[6]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {LED[6]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN V14 [get_ports {LED[7]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {LED[7]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN V13 [get_ports {LED[8]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {LED[8]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN V3 [get_ports {LED[9]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {LED[9]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN W3 [get_ports {LED[10]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {LED[10]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN U3 [get_ports {LED[11]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {LED[11]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN P3 [get_ports {LED[12]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {LED[12]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN N3 [get_ports {LED[13]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {LED[13]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN P1 [get_ports {LED[14]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {LED[14]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN L1 [get_ports {LED[15]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {LED[15]}]


#7 segment display
set_property PACKAGE_PIN W7 [get_ports {seg[0]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {seg[0]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN W6 [get_ports {seg[1]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {seg[1]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN U8 [get_ports {seg[2]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {seg[2]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN V8 [get_ports {seg[3]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {seg[3]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN U5 [get_ports {seg[4]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {seg[4]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN V5 [get_ports {seg[5]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {seg[5]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN U7 [get_ports {seg[6]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {seg[6]}]

set_property PACKAGE_PIN V7 [get_ports dp]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports dp]

set_property PACKAGE_PIN U2 [get_ports {an[0]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {an[0]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN U4 [get_ports {an[1]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {an[1]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN V4 [get_ports {an[2]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {an[2]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN W4 [get_ports {an[3]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {an[3]}]


##Buttons
set_property PACKAGE_PIN U18 [get_ports btnC]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports btnC]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN T18 [get_ports btnU]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports btnU]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN W19 [get_ports btnL]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports btnL]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN T17 [get_ports btnR]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports btnR]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN U17 [get_ports btnD]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports btnD]



#Pmod Header JA
#Sch name = JA1
set_property PACKAGE_PIN J1 [get_ports {JA[0]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {JA[0]}]
##Sch name = JA2
set_property PACKAGE_PIN L2 [get_ports {JA[1]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {JA[1]}]
##Sch name = JA3
set_property PACKAGE_PIN J2 [get_ports {JA[2]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {JA[2]}]
#Sch name = JA4
set_property PACKAGE_PIN G2 [get_ports {JA[3]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {JA[3]}]
#Sch name = JA7
set_property PACKAGE_PIN H1 [get_ports {JA[4]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {JA[4]}]
#Sch name = JA8
set_property PACKAGE_PIN K2 [get_ports {JA[5]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {JA[5]}]
#Sch name = JA9
set_property PACKAGE_PIN H2 [get_ports {JA[6]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {JA[6]}]
#Sch name = JA10
set_property PACKAGE_PIN G3 [get_ports {JA[7]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {JA[7]}]



##Pmod Header JB
##Sch name = JB1
#set_property PACKAGE_PIN A14 [get_ports {JB[0]}]
#set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {JB[0]}]
##Sch name = JB2
#set_property PACKAGE_PIN A16 [get_ports {JB[1]}]
#set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {JB[1]}]
##Sch name = JB3
#set_property PACKAGE_PIN B15 [get_ports {JB[2]}]
#set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {JB[2]}]
##Sch name = JB4
#set_property PACKAGE_PIN B16 [get_ports {JB[3]}]
#set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {JB[3]}]
##Sch name = JB7
#set_property PACKAGE_PIN A15 [get_ports {JB[4]}]
#set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {JB[4]}]
##Sch name = JB8
#set_property PACKAGE_PIN A17 [get_ports {JB[5]}]
#set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {JB[5]}]
##Sch name = JB9
#set_property PACKAGE_PIN C15 [get_ports {JB[6]}]
#set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {JB[6]}]
##Sch name = JB10
#set_property PACKAGE_PIN C16 [get_ports {JB[7]}]
#set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {JB[7]}]



##Pmod Header JC
##Sch name = JC1
#set_property PACKAGE_PIN K17 [get_ports {JC[0]}]
#set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {JC[0]}]
##Sch name = JC2
#set_property PACKAGE_PIN M18 [get_ports {JC[1]}]
#set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {JC[1]}]
##Sch name = JC3
#set_property PACKAGE_PIN N17 [get_ports {JC[2]}]
#set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {JC[2]}]
##Sch name = JC4
#set_property PACKAGE_PIN P18 [get_ports {JC[3]}]
#set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {JC[3]}]
##Sch name = JC7
#set_property PACKAGE_PIN L17 [get_ports {JC[4]}]
#set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {JC[4]}]
##Sch name = JC8
#set_property PACKAGE_PIN M19 [get_ports {JC[5]}]
#set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {JC[5]}]
##Sch name = JC9
#set_property PACKAGE_PIN P17 [get_ports {JC[6]}]
#set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {JC[6]}]
##Sch name = JC10
#set_property PACKAGE_PIN R18 [get_ports {JC[7]}]
#set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {JC[7]}]


#Pmod Header JXADC
#Sch name = XA1_P
set_property PACKAGE_PIN J3 [get_ports {vauxp6}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {vauxp6}]
#Sch name = XA2_P
set_property PACKAGE_PIN L3 [get_ports {vauxp14}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {vauxp14}]
#Sch name = XA3_P
set_property PACKAGE_PIN M2 [get_ports {vauxp7}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {vauxp7}]
#Sch name = XA4_P
set_property PACKAGE_PIN N2 [get_ports {vauxp15}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {vauxp15}]
#Sch name = XA1_N
set_property PACKAGE_PIN K3 [get_ports {vauxn6}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {vauxn6}]
#Sch name = XA2_N
set_property PACKAGE_PIN M3 [get_ports {vauxn14}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {vauxn14}]
#Sch name = XA3_N
set_property PACKAGE_PIN M1 [get_ports {vauxn7}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {vauxn7}]
#Sch name = XA4_N
set_property PACKAGE_PIN N1 [get_ports {vauxn15}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {vauxn15}]



##VGA Connector
#set_property PACKAGE_PIN G19 [get_ports {vgaRed[0]}]
#set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {vgaRed[0]}]
#set_property PACKAGE_PIN H19 [get_ports {vgaRed[1]}]
#set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {vgaRed[1]}]
#set_property PACKAGE_PIN J19 [get_ports {vgaRed[2]}]
#set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {vgaRed[2]}]
#set_property PACKAGE_PIN N19 [get_ports {vgaRed[3]}]
#set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {vgaRed[3]}]
#set_property PACKAGE_PIN N18 [get_ports {vgaBlue[0]}]
#set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {vgaBlue[0]}]
#set_property PACKAGE_PIN L18 [get_ports {vgaBlue[1]}]
#set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {vgaBlue[1]}]
#set_property PACKAGE_PIN K18 [get_ports {vgaBlue[2]}]
#set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {vgaBlue[2]}]
#set_property PACKAGE_PIN J18 [get_ports {vgaBlue[3]}]
#set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {vgaBlue[3]}]
#set_property PACKAGE_PIN J17 [get_ports {vgaGreen[0]}]
#set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {vgaGreen[0]}]
#set_property PACKAGE_PIN H17 [get_ports {vgaGreen[1]}]
#set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {vgaGreen[1]}]
#set_property PACKAGE_PIN G17 [get_ports {vgaGreen[2]}]
#set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {vgaGreen[2]}]
#set_property PACKAGE_PIN D17 [get_ports {vgaGreen[3]}]
#set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {vgaGreen[3]}]
#set_property PACKAGE_PIN P19 [get_ports Hsync]
#set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports Hsync]
#set_property PACKAGE_PIN R19 [get_ports Vsync]
#set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports Vsync]


##USB-RS232 Interface
#set_property PACKAGE_PIN B18 [get_ports RsRx]
#set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports RsRx]
#set_property PACKAGE_PIN A18 [get_ports RsTx]
#set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports RsTx]


##USB HID (PS/2)
#set_property PACKAGE_PIN C17 [get_ports PS2Clk]
#set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports PS2Clk]
#set_property PULLUP true [get_ports PS2Clk]
#set_property PACKAGE_PIN B17 [get_ports PS2Data]
#set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports PS2Data]
#set_property PULLUP true [get_ports PS2Data]


##Quad SPI Flash
##Note that CCLK_0 cannot be placed in 7 series devices. You can access it using the
##STARTUPE2 primitive.
#set_property PACKAGE_PIN D18 [get_ports {QspiDB[0]}]
#set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {QspiDB[0]}]
#set_property PACKAGE_PIN D19 [get_ports {QspiDB[1]}]
#set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {QspiDB[1]}]
#set_property PACKAGE_PIN G18 [get_ports {QspiDB[2]}]
#set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {QspiDB[2]}]
#set_property PACKAGE_PIN F18 [get_ports {QspiDB[3]}]
#set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {QspiDB[3]}]
#set_property PACKAGE_PIN K19 [get_ports QspiCSn]
#set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports QspiCSn]
```

**top.xdc**

```
create_generated_clock -name cd/div_clk_r -source [get_ports CLK100MHZ] -divide_by 2 [get_pins cd/div_clk_r_reg/Q]
```

Comment: I wonder where did the clock interaction go after BUFG insertion. Did you not create generated clock at BUFG output (not input)?

Comment: @MituRaj the generated clock I have is: `create_generated_clock -name cd/clk -source [get_ports CLK100MHZ] -divide_by 1000 [get_pins cd/div_clk_reg/Q]` being `CLK100MHZ` the Basys 3 main clock (input port) and `div_clk_reg` the flop that generates the divided clock output.

Comment: That's at the input of BUFG then. I think still it should have propagated through BUFG and shown in the clock list instead of disappearing. Hmm interesting.

Comment: @MituRaj The code is very small, I can provide it for experimenting.

Comment: I have tried it and the generated clock successfully propagated via BUFG to clock tree, as well as it is shown in the clock interactions. I guess you might have added some timing exceptions, that's why not shown in your case.

Comment: @MituRaj correct, I retried from zero and now I get something that makes sense. Added to my response (EDIT 3). Thanks.

Comment: However there are not really clock interactions (the ones in green), because there is no data being launched between two clock domains, but Vivado still reports it by mistake because the generated clock was created on Q pin. If you create this generated clock at BUFG input (get_pins {buf0g0/I} or so) instead, you can see Vivado correctly shows the clock interactions with black regions between clock domains, instead of green.

Comment: @MituRaj but is that recommendable? As far as I understand, BUFG is supposed to provide a buffer capable of driving a big fan out network with very low skew. If `BUFG` is set at the input, this property is lost, isn't it? Because the 'normal' register used to actually divide the clock will be the one driving such a big fan out?

Comment: That's not what I said. BUFG should be at the output of divider itself. But the generated clock constraint should be created at the input pin of bufg rather than output pin of divider. This has no effect on Placement and Routing. It just changes the starting point of clock for timing analysis. So that clock interactions are correctly interpreted for analysis.

Answer (score 2):

Yea that wont work without the tool whining on most FPGA platforms because you cannot make a clock like that in something intended to be synthesisable (Well you sort of can, sometimes, but it confuses the hell out of the timing closure tools and is not a good idea).

Instead make your divider output a single clock wide 'clock enable' pulse every time the divider rolls over and do "if rising_edge(clk100) and clk_en then'.
This way everything runs in the same clock domain, so the timing analysis is trivial, you are not routing clocks in logic fabric, and the synthesis and implementation tools wont bitch about clock buffers.

Comment: I see, thanks. Here is an article that treats this topic: https://chipmunklogic.com/digital-logic-design/clock-dividers-using-flip-flops-in-rtl-on-fpga/